# Calling variable from other class by inserting its name as variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is this, I wanted to have a bunch of variables which I called GlobalVariables that I can use and change on demand. I used dictionary for that which was rather usefull however 2 problems arose. First that I can use only one type and second is that later I wanted to use those variables in multiple class.

My next solution was to use separate class to define variables there and use them like GlobalStatus.Variable. Seemed like a good idea however now I am faced with the problem that I need to call my GlobalStatus variables by other variable. I can't put it into words(thats the reason why I am asking this question) but here is how it was done with Dictionary.

```
foreach (string String in Array) {
     if (GlobalStatus[String] == "Test") {
     ...
     }
}
```

Can I emulate this behavour using Class to store variables, or I should use another way to store said variables?

Comment: You should *probably* use another way.  What are you really trying to accomplish here?  Having a global dumping ground of variables is usually not a great idea.  Why do you need this?

Comment: In my code i require bunch of variables(currently 7 but could increase) that I need to track and change as code executes. Those are pretty simple usually it's either true/false or a string. I figured best way to easely access them is to store them somwhere.

Comment: Should they be `static` values?  You can define them as `static` properties in a class and access them anywhere.  Whether or not that's the *correct* approach is still anybody's guess.  "I need to store values" doesn't really define much about the structure of things.  It's *likely* that there's a better way to build whatever you're building, but that might be too large a discussion for a Stack Overflow question.  In the scope of the question, perhaps you're just looking for `static` properties?

Comment: They are indeed static properties, however that still doesn't give me an ability to call them GlobalStatues.String (Where String is a string variable) this is the functionality or alternative to it that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Also you say "too large a discussion for Stack Overflow question". Would you have any suggestions where I could attempt to bring this discussion to?

Comment: do you want to discuss this in chat? I am having hard time to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I guess, i never used chat before in StackOverflow.

Comment: @JevgenijVisockij: What you're trying to do is possible, but generally along the lines of losing a lot of type safety.  You could use a `Dictionary<string, object>`, you could use reflection.  You *might* be able to make a generic method on your static object which returns the correct type and manually specify the type argument when calling the method.  Just an idea, never tried doing this specific thing with generics.  In general, wanting to call variables by their string name is *often* (but not always) a broken design, and wanting to have global variables is *often* a broken design.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158186/calling-variable-from-other-class-by-inserting-its-name-as-variable

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to write there ;/

Comment: try now, I tried to add you

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I still get "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is:
We have an array of 2 strings: name and value. This is called requirement. Requirements are kept in global class as static variables. How to compare requirement in the class with a requirement parameter like new array string[2].

After some discussion one of possible solutions

1. Use array of requirements in global class
2. Use requirement name as integer instead of string type.

Then requirement name can be used as index of global array.

Answer (score 1):

As David pointed out you probably wanna avoid global variables unless you have a good reason to have them.

That said, if I were you I'd probably make something like

```
namespace Global{
public class Options{
public static Options _Instance;
void Awake(){
if (_Instance == null)
{
_Instance = this;
}
}
}    
}
```

Then you may call this global Options class from anywhere using the Singleton _Instance variable by saying `Global.Options._Instance.*Your variable or method*`

This way you can have a namespace called Global which can hold your global variables in an orderly fashion.

I advise you to divide your variables into classes instead of having a dictionary to hold it all, unless there is good reason to.

Comment: As others pointed out I should probably search for better way to do this, but as it stands this answers my question, so I am accepting the answer.

Comment: Usually you would divide variables into categories in their respective classes. What variables will you be making and for what purpose?

Comment: Ehh I can't accept to answers. Sorry I had to remove accepted one from you Yuri S was kind enough to have a chat in Skype and figured my actual problem and solution, so it would make more sense for him to have an accepted answer.